# Violin plot of a data frame

Tags: r, plot

I have a `data.frame`, for example:

```
df = data.frame(AAA=rnorm(100,1,1),BBB=rnorm(100,2,1.5),CCC=rnorm(100,1.5,1.2))
```

And I'd like to plot each of its columns in a joint violin plot.

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
names(df)[1] = 'x'
do.call('vioplot', c(df,col="red",drawRect=FALSE))
```

What I want to do next is to plot the colnames of `df` as x-axis labels rather than the default x-axis labels of `vioplot` and in addition in a way that they don't run over each other. I imagine this can be achieved either by spreading the columns of `df` in the plot or by slanting the x-axis labels. But I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 9):

Probably easier to use ggplot

```
df = data.frame(AAA=rnorm(100,1,1),
                BBB=rnorm(100,2,1.5),
                CCC=rnorm(100,1.5,1.2))
```

Need to transform the data into something ggplot can handle:

```
df.m <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = NULL)
```

and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.m, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I like the `ggplot` solution the best, but here is how you would do it with `do.call`:

```
do.call(vioplot,c(unname(df),col='red',drawRect=FALSE,names=list(names(df))))
```

[image]

Notably, you wouldn't have to do `names(df)[1] = 'x'` because you remove the names with `unname`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried dropping the `do.call` call and doing them individually.

```
vioplot(df[,"AAA"], df[,"BBB"], df[,"CCC"], 
        col = "red", drawRect = FALSE,names = names(df))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a loop for now (my real data.frame has many columns), but I guess I can resort to that if I won't find a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option is using the `ggviolin` function from [ggpubr](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/) with long formatted data like this:

```r
df = data.frame(AAA=rnorm(100,1,1),BBB=rnorm(100,2,1.5),CCC=rnorm(100,1.5,1.2))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpubr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggviolin(x = "name",
           y = "value")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Pretty sure reshape2 is deprecated now, best to use tidyr instead.

Comment: @user438383, Yes you are right! Changed it to pivot_longer, thanks!