# R violin plot overlay 2 dataframes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say you have two dataframes

```
M1 <- data.frame(sample(1:3, 500, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)
M2 <- data.frame(sample(1:3, 500, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)
```

and I want to overlay them as violin plots as seen here:
[Overlay violin plots ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483074/overlay-violin-plots-ggplot2)

but I have 2 dataframes like above (but bigger) not one with 3 columns as in the example above

I have tried the advice using melt as seen here:
[Violin plot of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960614/violin-plot-of-a-data-frame)

but I cant get it to overlay two dataframes

help is much appreciated:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(1)
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(2:4, 500, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
M1.melt <- melt(M1)
M2.melt <- melt(M2)
ggplot() +
  geom_violin(data=M1.melt, aes(x=variable,y=value),fill="lightblue",colour="blue")+
  geom_violin(data=M2.melt, aes(x=variable,y=value),fill="lightgreen",colour="green")
```

There are several issues. First, `data.frame(...)` does no take an `ncol` argument, so your code just generates a pair of 2-column data frames with the second column called `ncol` with all values = 5. If you want 5 columns (do you??) then you have to use `matrix(...)` as above.

Second, you do need to use `melt(...)` to reorganize the dataframes from "wide" format (categories in 5 different columns) to "long" format (all data in 1 column, called `value`, with categories distinguihsed by a second column, called `variable`).

Another way to do this combines the two dataframes first:

```
M3 <- rbind(M1,M2)
M3$group <- rep(c("A","B"),each=100)
M3.melt <- melt(M3, id="group")
ggplot(M3.melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_violin(position="identity")
```

[image]

Note that this generates a slightly different plot because `ggplot` scales the width of the violins together, whereas in the earlier plot they were scaled separately.

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

To put the fill colors in a legend, you have to make them part of an aesthetic scale: put `fill=...` inside the call to `aes(...)` as follows.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_violin(data=M1.melt, aes(x=variable,y=value,fill="M1"),colour="blue")+
  geom_violin(data=M2.melt, aes(x=variable,y=value,fill="M2"),colour="green")+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Data Set",values=c(M1="lightblue",M2="lightgreen"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that works, just a thing I had to look up, adding ("  + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) ") will make the x-axis text not get scrunched, which was the case for me.

Comment: I chose the first option it makes more sense for what I am doing. But I want a color legend, how do you do that with the first method? thanks